# Приоритет выполнения в коде

Tags: javascript

При создании объекта одному из свойств можно приписать вызов функции. Например:

```
function test() {
    console.log('tester')
}

var obj = {
    a: 10,
    b: test() 
}
```

По идее, присваивается результат функции. Вроде так и есть. Но по факту, даже без вызова (просто при наличии подобной функции у объекта), это свойство объекта самовызывается.

Как вариант - скорее всего, потому что в функции присутствует `console.log`, который и вызывает себя. Но вот должен ли он это делать при объявлении объекта?

Так же как и:

```
var testA = console.log( 1 )

var testB = function(value) {
  console.log( value )
} 

var testC = testB(3)

testB(2)
```

Тут тоже - вроде по приоритету вызов функции должен быть первым. Но по факту - сначала вызывается (при присвоении переменной - должно быть в последнюю очередь), `testA`, потом `testB`, а уже потом сам вызов функции `testB(2)`

Вроде же в приоритете должно быть выполнение функции, а только лишь потом присвоение. ЧЯДНТ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При создании объекта подобным образом:

```
var obj = {
    b: test()
}
```

в `obj.b` попадает **результат выполнения** функции `test` (`undefined`), то есть функция `test` выполняется в момент создания объекта

Если функция должна вызываться позже в виде `obj.b()`, то в `b` нужно помещать не результат выполнения, а ссылку на функцию:

```
var obj = {
    b: test
}
```

---

Во втором примере в `testA` присваивается результат выполнения функции `console.log`. В процессе её выполнения в консоль выводится `1`, а её результат (`undefined`) попадает в `testA`

После чего в `testB` присваивается безымянная функция, в `testC` - результат выполнения `testB` (что опять-таки приводит к вызову `console.log`), и в конце просто вызывается `testB`

Comment: Разве не должна сначала функция выполняться, потом присваивание( и выполнение функции, при операции присвоения). По сути же сначала просто объявляются переменные(без присвоения). Потом объявляются function declaration( без выполнения). Потом должно же быть выполнение функций, а лишь потом - присвоение переменных ? Или всё идёт по порядку, после объявления переменных и function declaration ?
Грубо говоря - "вне очереди" - лишь объявление переменной "var" и function declaration ? Всё остальное по порядку ?
Получается присвоение переменной (если стоит раньше) - быстрее выполнения функции ?

Comment: @Dwarf в конструкции `a = func();` действительно сначала выполняется функция `func`, а затем происходит присваивание результата её выполнения в переменную `a`. Об этом я и писал в ответе, и именно это происходит в представленном вами коде

Comment: Благодарю Вас. Простите, просто хочется докопаться до некоторого понимания. На https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence, в таблице приоритетов операторов - "вызов функции", имеет приоритет "19". А оператор "присваивание" - имеет приоритет в "3". Вот и думаю что сначала (как ни крути), выполнится функция (более приоритетный оператор), а лишь после - присваивание (как менее приоритетный оператор). Так по итогу (2й пример), выполняется сначала выводится "1", в консоли, а не "2" (как казалось бы, должно быть "2". Т.к func, выдаёт именно "2")

Comment: @Dwarf в строке `var testA = console.log(1)` выполняется сначала функция, а потом присваивание, да. Поэтому выводится единица. Следующие строки кода выполняются позже, потому что это уже следующие операции (token/statement-ы)

Comment: То есть приоритет операторов, действует ТОЛЬКО в процессе выполнения выражения (к примеру var a = 2 + func() - в процессе присваивания, сначала выполнится 'func()', потом выполнится сложение). А приоритет выполнения СТРОКИ кода НЕ ЗАВИСИТ от оператора. Он будет по порядку (исключая 'setTimeout'). Будь там хоть присваивание, хоть выполнение функции - не важно (не берем в расчёт funciton declaration, в процессе инициализации, continue). Это верное утверждение ?Или в чем то неправ ?

Comment: Получается приоритеты операторов, не могут поменять порядок выполнения СТРОК кода ?

Comment: @Dwarf да. Стоит только отметить, что под "строкой" кода подразумевается цельное "выражение" (например, объявление `obj` в вашем примере занимает 4 строки текста, но выражение это одно). Сам `setTimeout`, кстати, исключением не является - просто функция, переданная в него, выполняется асинхронно и позже, но с базовыми приоритетами выполнения это не связано